# How to add Fade-in Fade-Out to a looping audio. Mozilla Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am making an audio editing plugin. One of the requirements is to loop the audio n number of times during playback. I have achieved this by using the `src.loop = true` attribute of the **AudioBufferSourceNode** and then calling `src.stop(timeToStop)` where **timeToStop = this.ac.currentTime + this.delay + (this.getDuration() * this.loopCount)** . Meaning I am not editing or changing the audioBuffer at all. Now when i apply fadeIn fadeOut to the audioBuffer, fadeIn is replicated for each loop and fadeOut is not applied (this is because i belive the endTime of fadeOut becomes larger than audio Duration). I am required to apply fadeIn at the **start** of the **1st** loop and fadeOut at the **end** of the **last or nth** loop. Can I achieve this without changing or replicating the audioBuffer n times?

These are my methods:

Method to start the source audio File.

```
play({start} = {}) { //play is called at the end when all effects are applied to audioBuffer

        if(this.isPaused){
            this.isPaused = false;
            this.isPlaying = true;
            this.resumeState();
            return;
        }

        if(!start){
            start = 0;
        }

        if(this.ac.state == 'suspended'){
            this.resumeState();
        }

        this.enqueue(() =>
            this.promiseInit()
                .then(() => {
                    this.createSource();
                    this.src.connect(this.masterGain);
                    if(this.isLooping){
                        this.src.loop = true;
                        this.src.loopStart = 0;
                    }
                    this.startSrc(start);
                    this.src.stop(this.ac.currentTime + this.delay + (this.getDuration() * this.loopCount)); //delay will always be zero
                    this.savePlayPosition();
                    this.fireEvent('playing', this.name);
                })
        )
        this.flushQueue();
    }
```

Method to apply the fadeOut and fadeIn effects to audioBuffer

```
fadeOut({start, end}) { 
        console.log("Fade out called. Start is = " + start + " and end = " + end);
        this.enqueue(() =>
            this.promiseInit()
                .then(() => WebAudio.fadeOutBuffer({
                    buffer: this.getAudioBuffer(),
                    start,
                    end,
                    threshold: this.fadeThreshold
                }))
                .then((renderedBuffer) => {
                    this.loadNewBuffer(renderedBuffer);
                    this.fireEvent("effect-applied", this.name, "fadeOut");
                })
                .catch((err) => this.fireEvent('error', this.name, err))
        );
    }

    fadeIn({start, end}) { // start is zero
        console.log("Fade in called. Start is = " + start + " and end = " + end);
        this.enqueue(() =>
            this.promiseInit()
                .then(() => WebAudio.fadeInBuffer({
                    buffer: this.getAudioBuffer(),
                    start,
                    end,
                    threshold: this.fadeThreshold
                }))
                .then((renderedBuffer) => {
                    this.loadNewBuffer(renderedBuffer);
                    this.fireEvent("effect-applied", this.name, "fadeIn");
                })
                .catch((err) => this.fireEvent('error', this.name, err))
        );
    }
```

Virtual Methods for fadeIn fadeOut to edit the AudioBuffer using OfflineAudioContext

```
static fadeOutBuffer({buffer, start = 0, end = buffer.duration, threshold = 0}) {
        let ac = new OfflineAudioContext(buffer.numberOfChannels, buffer.length, buffer.sampleRate);
        const source = new AudioBufferSourceNode(ac, {buffer});
        const gain = new GainNode(ac);
        gain.gain.setValueAtTime(1, start);
        gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(threshold, end);
        gain.gain.setValueAtTime(1, end);
        source.connect(gain).connect(ac.destination);
        source.start();
        return ac.startRendering()
    }

    static fadeInBuffer({buffer, start = 0, end = buffer.duration, threshold = 0}) {
        let ac = new OfflineAudioContext(buffer.numberOfChannels, buffer.length, buffer.sampleRate);
        const source = new AudioBufferSourceNode(ac, {buffer});
        const gain = new GainNode(ac);
        gain.gain.setValueAtTime(threshold, start);
        gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, end);
        source.connect(gain).connect(ac.destination);
        source.start();
        return ac.startRendering()
    }
```